# What's going wrong with my code for Euler Project #1?

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me where it is my program is going wrong here? I just don't see it...

```
x_3 = []
i=0
while 3*i < 1000:
    sum_3 = 3*i
    x_3.extend([sum_3])
    i += 1

x_5 = []
j = 0
while 5*j < 1000:
    sum_5 = 5*j
    j += 1
    x_5.extend([sum_5])

answer = sum(x_5) + sum(x_3)
print(answer)
266333
```

Which is not correct.

Comment: Kindly add more context to your question. It is much preferable for users to not have to check up on an external source.

Comment: Please (re-)read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to explain what you're trying to do, and what your program was supposed to do (instead of print `266333`).  266333 is a perfectly good number --- there's nothing obviously "not correct" about it.  Quote whatever you have to from Project Euler #1 to make it clear, and provide proper attribution, including a link to the original.  Your question should stand on its own.

Comment: Also try searching for "Project Euler" next time.  There's already several answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Yes, I see now that this is the same problem as [Project Euler - #1 Python wrong solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785902/project-euler-1-python-wrong-solution)

Comment: And thanks everyone for the comments, I'll make sure my next question is more clear in purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the following to calculate this:

```
def calcEuler(x1,x2):
    return sum(num for num in xrange(1000) if not (num % x1 and num % x2))

print(calcEuler(3,5))
```

You seem to be adding up all number that are between 0 and 1000 that are multiples of 3 and 5.  However, you are double recording the ones that are multiples of both, like 15, 30, etc. So, I combined the two loops.